# bot framework skype hyperlink

Tags: botframework, microsoft-skype-bot

I have a formflow bot which has following fields:

- Site Name
- Parent Site URL (need to pass hyperlink)
- Site Owner

There is no regex used for the hyperlink.

Whenever I run from webchat channel, it works as expected. But in Skype bot, passing in a hyperlink gives some issue; if I pass text instead of hyperlink, it works fine.
These values gets saved in a SharePoint list using the API.

Has anyone faced such issue/ Anyone know what needs to be done?

Comment: Could you please post your code related to the URL within your form? If you can, also include any processing you do to the URL itself after the submission. Additionally, is there any specific format that the URL is passed in as for the hyperlink field (http vs https etc)?

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for your reply.
I was able to solve the issue by removing the hyperlink tags before saving the values in the SP list.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to post an answer to your own question here detailing a bit more about how you solved it.

Comment: I solved by removing the hyperlinks as below:


newGroupMailboxEmailAddress = Regex.Replace(MailboxrequestFormData.GroupMailboxEmailAddress, "</?(a|A).*?>", "");
This will remove the hyperlinks tag and the data will be saved in the form of text.
My above values are coming from FormFlow.